# Cómo duplicar nuevas filas condicionadas a un DataFrame específico en CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Tengo un `file.csv` con 16 filas y 2 columnas. Cada tipo representa un tipo de personalidad, mientras la descripción otorga características de cada tipo de personalidad. Cada descripción es prácticamente un texto, con puntos, comas, quotchars, saltos de líneas, etc.

**Forma del csv:**

```
TIPO   | DESCRIPCION
 a1    |  este tipo de personalidad...\nComen peras como los monos...\nSi es que...
 b2    |  descrip.b2
 c3    |  descrip.c3
 d4    |    ...
...16  |    ...
```

Quiero duplicar un tipo si es que en su descripción hay algún salto de línea. Entendiéndolo de otro modo, si en la descripción hay un salto de línea, 'guardar' ese texto usando el mismo tipo, luego, en el siguiente salto de línea, 'guardar' ese pedazo de texto en otra fila con el mismo tipo.

**OUTPUT esperado:**

```
TIPO   | DESCRIPCION
 a1    |  Este tipo de personalidad...
 a1    |  Comen peras como los monos...
 a1    |  Si es que...
 b2    |  descrip.b2
 c3    |  descrip.c3
 ...   |     ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con pandas así:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("tu-csv-aqui.csv")

# dividir la columna donde hay nuevas líneas y convertirla en una serie
s = df["DESCRIPCION"].str.split("\n").apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()

0  0     este tipo de personalidad...
   1    Comen peras como los monos...
   2                     Si es que...

# quitar el segundo índice para que el dataframe y la serie compartan índices
s.index = s.index.droplevel(1)

# darle un nombre para unirla al dataframe
s.name = "DESCRIPCION"

# eliminar columna original
del df["DESCRIPCION"]

# unir la serie con el dataframe, basado en el índice compartido
df = df.join(s)

  TIPO                    DESCRIPCION
0   a1   este tipo de personalidad...
0   a1  Comen peras como los monos...
0   a1                   Si es que...
```

Comment: hay que especificar que la librería que utilizas es pandas (ya que tengo csv y pandas en las etiquetas). Por lo demás, todo bien!

Comment: Ah, tienes razón, lo siento. Pensé que era obvio por la etiqueta "pandas" en tu pregunta. Igual, editaré mi respuesta.

Comment: También esto agregará una nueva columna de índices unnamed, pero para esto se resuelve `df.to_csv(index = False)`. Gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: esta solución dio varios valores NaN, sabes por qué?  [CSV con tu solución](https://github.com/GUNTERMAXIMUS/mbti/blob/master/mbti_new.csv), [CSV original](https://github.com/GUNTERMAXIMUS/mbti/blob/master/mbti_datasets.csv)

Comment: Es porque en tu primera celda de descripción, hay partes con dos nuevas líneas consecutivas, con nada entre ellas. Quita los valores NaN con ```df.dropna()```

Comment: Hice lo que quieres hacer con tu csv arriba. Creo que no hay NaNs, sino cadenas de nada. Así que haz ```df = df[df["descripcion"].str.len() > 0]``` después de ```df = df.join(s)``` para quitar cadenas de longitud == 0.

Comment: Si hay NaNs, si chequeo con `print(new_df['descripcion'].isnull())` me indica que hay varios NaNs donde en el csv aparecen como cadenas vacías. Pero si luego uso `new_df = pd.read_csv(root_new_fn).dropna()` y re-escribo `to_csv`, resulta.

Comment: Utilicé lo que me comentaste recientemente, pero al usar `.isnull()` me seguía indicando NaN values.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104948/discussion-between-gunter-sama-and-xandermorrison).